# Отправка запроса в определенное время

Tags: phpmyadmin, php, mysql

Здравствуйте, необходимо реализовать возможность отправлять сообщения в выбранное время (с помощью календаря).
Я так понял, что надо сделать сравнение по времени, поэтому сделал БД и занёс туда данные о времени. Далее, если наступает нужная дата, надо чтобы скрипт находил в БД всю эту строку и подставлял в переменные. Как это сделать?

Так же есть условие, если из столбца4 берется данное значение, то необходимо чтобы вся строка выделялась и заносилась в переменные. С помощью какой функции это можно сделать на MySQL, или как правильнее?

> > > [**Пример таблицы**](http://imageshack.com/a/img513/3756/oanh.png)

Comment: можно написать процедуру(не на всех хостингах имеется такая возможность) либо запускать по крону. В общем с определенным максимальным интервалом времени запускать процедуру либо скрипт который проверяет условие

Comment: Хочу сделать сделать по крону, чтоб запрос с скрипту был раз в минуту. А скрипт уже должен сравнивать, наступило ли время указаное в БД или нет, и потом уже брать данные из БД и подставлять

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем случае, примерно так:

1. Создаете PHP-скрипт. В начале скрипта прописываете строчку *#!/usr/local/bin/php* (это путь к интерпретатору, он может отличаться на вашем хостинге) и проставляете права доступа достаточные для запуска. Важно убедиться, что у вас в скрипте используются Unix-переносы строк (LF), а не виндовские CRLF.
2. Я так понимаю, вам нужно выбрать первые три столбца если дата в четвертом стобце меньше или равна текущей? Если я верно понял, значит внутри скрипта подключаетесь к БД и делаете запрос вроде *SELECT столбец1,столбец2,столбец3 FROM таблица WHERE стобец4<=NOW()*.
3. Устанавливаете крон на скрипт. Как именно это сделать на вашем хостинге вы найдете в документации хостера.

Comment: Спасибо, а если в столбце4 будут несколько совпадающих дат?

Comment: @XenK, либо итерируйте по ним в цикле, либо добавьте в конец запроса *ORDER BY столбец4 LIMIT 1*. Первый вариант позволит обработать несколько записей, второй гарантировано выдаст одну запись в порядке очереди.

Comment: @BArtWell, если есть совпадающих даты, мне необходимо поочередно подставить данные в переменные, и выполнить запрос. Для этого подойдет метод "ORDER BY столбец4 LIMIT 1"?

Comment: @XenK, нет, вы не поняли, что я имел ввиду. Посмотрите, по этой ссылке есть пример организации цикла для прохождения по всем полученным строкам из запроса, это то, что вам нужно, только запрос поменяйте: http://us1.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php